# Using jQuery UI switchClass method to change class of 13 elements at once?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, setinterval

I have 13 different elements with the following class on all of these elements defined `candidate`

Now I also have 13 different classes for these same elements defined as well, such as follows:

`can1`, `can2`, `can3`, `can4`, `can5`, `can6`, `can7`, `can8`, `can9`, `can10`, `can11`, `can12`, `can13`

I need to switch each elements class SIMULTANEOUSLY at the same time once every 5 seconds or so, but keep the `candidate` class defined on all of them, just need to change the `can` classes.  And I need to change the classes so that they decrement by 1 every 5 seconds, except when can1 is defined, it will switch to can13 instead.  So...

can1 becomes can13
can2 becomes can1
can3 becomes can2
and so on... all the way to can13 becomming can12

And during the class change, it needs to animate to that class as well, so I'm thinking I need `switchClass` to accomplish this.  But what's the BEST and most productive way to do this exactly?

Could grab all elements in 1 go using:

`$(".candidate").switchClass(... code);`

But I now I'm screwed with getting the old class and changing to the new class, so how would I do that?

Also, I have defined a `data-class` on each element with the actual NUMBER that represents the `can` class.  So, if that element has a class of `can1`, than `data-class` has a value of `1`, if that element has a class of `can2`, than `data-class` on that element has a value of `2`, and so on...

How can I use this to my advantage and decrement the `can` classes last number value every 5 seconds?  So I noticed that the `switchClass` method can have a `queue` option set to `false` which is probably something that I want, but again, how to use it for this purpose??  And am wanting something like 500 ms for the animation of `switchClass`

Do I have to do a `.each()` on this?

Comment: You can add one more class to each as placeholder and use that to identify all the objects. use addClass and removeClass instead of switch class to remove candidate and add it again whenever necessary.

Comment: How would I use `removeClass` and `addClass` with animation between the removed class to the added class?  Cause once I remove the class it will mess it all up.  IT MUST animate from the old class to the new class.  And why do I need to add another class??  Don't I have enough information on each element to be able to do what I want to do with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better if the classes ranged from 0 to 12 instead of 1 to 13.  This way you can easily use modular arithmetic.  If they have to be 1 to 13, simply do the addition after computing the modulus, i.e., `nextClassId = (currentClassId % 13) + 1;` (but that seems more confusing to me).

```
setInterval(function() {
   $('.candidate').each(function() {
        var $this = $(this),
            currentClassId =  Number($this.data('class')),
            nextClassId = (currentClassId + 1) % 13;
        $this.switchClass('can' + currentClassId, 'can' + nextClassId);
        $this.data('class', nextClassId);
   });
}, 5000);
```

Working fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/7dYXh/

Comment: Ok, I think you got it wrong, first I need animation between the classes, 2nd, I need it to decrease, not increase the `can` class number values and 3rd, I need it to all be done simultaneously!

Comment: Here's where I'm using it, but it's terrible:  http://opportunityfinance.net/Test/newest_conference-2013/meetcandidates.html  How can we make it smooth animation??

Comment: @SolomonClosson - I should have been clear that I wasn't providing a solution, but a template that you could use for one.

Comment: @SolomonClosson - I've updated it to decrement the class number. The logic is a little different, http://jsfiddle.net/Tt6yW/

Comment: @SolomonClosson - I looked at your code. I think one problem is that you're doing a DOM lookup in each loop.  Try this and see if it helps: http://jsfiddle.net/xwKe6/

Comment: Thanks, I got it using a for loop instead.  Cheers :)

Comment: But now there seems to be a problem with the height of the rotation for the images inside of the circles when rotating.  I think it's because I don't have a set pixel amount on this, and instead am using percentages...